# Как ограничить высоту JTextField при добавлении его в Box?

Tags: java, swing

Получается вот такая картина:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Текстовое поле добавляю так:

```
verticalBoxForTaskMainInfo.add(quantityField);
```

Box вертикальный

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Из доков с Oracle говорится:

> BoxLayout pays attention to a component's requested minimum,
>   preferred, and maximum sizes. While you are fine-tuning the layout,
>   you might need to adjust these sizes. ... For example, a button's
>   maximum size is generally the same as its preferred size. If you want
>   the button to be drawn wider when additional space is available, then
>   you need to change its maximum size.

Поэтому просто наложите на ваш `JTextField` ограничение по размеру, например:

```
jtext.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(Integer.MAX_VALUE, text.getMinimumSize().height));
```

Был уже похожий пример на [enSO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18405660/how-to-set-component-size-inside-container-with-boxlayout), где вопрос решается таким способом.

Comment: Лучше всего, конечно, использовать комбинации из layout менеджеров, чем ограничивать какой-то компонент.

Comment: @Arsenicum Зачем? Лишний код + дополнительные менеджеры слоев, когда можно обойтись без них одной строчкой.

Comment: По идее позиции и размеры компонентов должны зависеть от менеджеров слоёв, а не от самого компонента (т.е. компонент запрашивает у менеджера свои размеры). Благодаря этому компоненты изменяются динамически. Если вы вручную устанавливаете размеры, то они становятся статическими и из-за этого могут возникнуть проблемы.

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете создать новый горизонтальный BoxLayout, положить его в ваш вертикальный BoxLayout вместо JTextField, а сам JTextField уже положить внутрь горизонтального BoxLayout.